# Is this a valid JSON string?

Tags: java, json

i am not familiar with json but as far as i know this should be a valid JSON string

```
{text:" Klan: Fury Elo: 9004 ",color:gold,extra:[{text:">>[ INFO ]<<",clickEvent:{action:run_command,value:"/klan info Fury"},hoverEvent:{action:show_text,value:"Zobrazis informaci o klanu."},color:gray,bold:true},{text:" "},{text:">>[ JOIN ]<<",color:green,bold:true,clickEvent:{action:run_command,value:"/klan join Fury"},hoverEvent:{action:show_text,value:"Podas zadost o vstoupeni do klanu."}}]}
```

But i am getting this error

```
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 3
```

Can somebody explain where is an error?

Comment: use http://jsonlint.com/ to see if it valid or not

Comment: Assuming this is for a /tellraw in Minecraft?

Comment: check it at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: It works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. Keys must be strings.

Whenever in doubt check out [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) - a great resource for format validation.

Answer (score 0):

Color and extra are not wrapped around double quote. For more information, read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON